# Find matching items between two arrays with difficult match condition

Tags: ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-5

We have two lists, a list of events each with an `id`, a `start_time`, and a `start_time_rage`. The `start_time_range` puts a tolerance around `start_time` to find near misses.

The objective is to filter the `current_matches`, to only include those that appear in the previous matches. An item "appears" in the list if the `id` matches and the `start_time` is within the range.

To achieve this, I have this loop, but with our ever increasing data size it is becoming very slow. I need to optimise it:

```
current_matches.select! do |match_row|
  previous_matches_collection.any? do |previous_match|
    previous_match[:item_id] == match_row[:item_id] &&
      previous_match[:start_time_range].include?(match_row[:start_time].to_f)
  end
end
```

If it were just the item_id I needed I could do this:

```
previous_ids = previous_matches_collection.collect{|i| i[:item_id] }
current_matches.select! do |match_row|
   previous_ids.include?(match_row[:item_id])
end
```

But I can't see a way of using that approach while matching the time condition in each item.

In terms of data, current_matches could be 300 and `previous_matches_collection` could be 1k+. Is there a way of doing this without iterating through 300,000 combinations?

edit - Sample data:

```
previous_matches_collection = [
  { item_id: 1, start_time: 1597094395.1195982, start_time_range: (1597094393.6195982..1597094396.6195982) },
  { item_id: 1, start_time: 1597095083.116646, start_time_range: (1597095081.616646..1597095084.616646) },
  { item_id: 1, start_time: 1597095403.028223, start_time_range: (1597095401.528223..1597095404.528223) },
  { item_id: 2, start_time: 1597098035.056944, start_time_range: (1597098033.556944..1597098036.556944) },
  { item_id: 3, start_time: 1597096073.4109557, start_time_range: (1597096071.9109557..1597096074.9109557) },
  { item_id: 4, start_time: 1597094785.6987526, start_time_range: (1597094784.1987526..1597094787.1987526) },
  { item_id: 4, start_time: 1597098077.41271, start_time_range: (1597098075.91271..1597098078.91271) }
]


current_matches = [
  { item_id: 1, start_time: 1597094395.9195982 },
  { item_id: 1, start_time: 1597095085.116646, },
  { item_id: 1, start_time: 1597095404.228223, },
  { item_id: 2, start_time: 1597094395.1195982 },
  { item_id: 4, start_time: 1597094395.1195982 },
  { item_id: 6, start_time: 1597094395.1195982 },
  { item_id: 17, start_time: 1597094395.1195982 }
]
```

Comment: can you add some sample data so we have a running example?

Comment: @Pascal, sample data added

Comment: can you post your full dataset somewhere (e.g. gist) so that we can experiment. I have some ideas but would like to do the performance measurement before I propose them.

Comment: @LesNightingill It'll take a while to find the largest dataset and unfiltered. Here's one that's been filtered, but may help: https://gist.github.com/tomdunning/34b7b6184ad4cff383ead45ac7ec1095

Comment: @LesNightingill sorry, fixed the gist ;)

Comment: @TomDunning the dataset in the gist is too small to show any performance issue... it's blazing fast. If someone has already provided a good answer, then ignore this, but if you still need help, please post a big dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy optimisation to make is to not use `any?` to find the correct `id`. Instead make a lookup hash to fetch all the `previous_matches_collection` elements with the correct `id` O(1).

Another optimization to make is to use [`cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) instead of [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F). The difference being that `cover?` only compares the element with the `begin` and `end` of a range. While `include?` uses [`succ`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html#class-Range-label-Custom+Objects+in+Ranges) (success eg. `1.succ #=> 2`) on the `begin` element to generate an collection though which it looks for the element.

```
("a".."z").include?("cc") #=> false
# is similar to:
# ["a", "b", "c", ..., "x", "y", "z"].include?("cc") #=> false

("a".."z").cover?("cc") #=> true
# is similar to:
# "a" <= "cc" && "cc <= "z" #=> true
```

The above code block demonstrates the difference between the two. In your scenario you just want to know if the value is within the range, so `cover?` suits better and is the faster option.

```
start_time_ranges_by_item_id = previous_matches_collection
  .group_by { |match| match[:item_id] }
  .transform_values { |matches| matches.map { |match| match[:start_time_range] } }
start_time_ranges_by_item_id.default = []
```

Now with the `start_time_ranges_by_item_id` hash build we should be able to jump to the relevant ranges directly and start the checks from there.

```
current_matches.select! do |match_row|
  item_id, start_time = match_row.values_at(:item_id, :start_time)
  start_time_ranges = start_time_ranges_by_item_id[item_id]
  start_time_ranges.any? { |range| range.cover?(start_time) }
end
```

Comment: Recall that [Hash.include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) implements `cover?` if the range's endpoints are numeric.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Their might be an optimization for `include?` for numerics. However it's better to be safe then sorry. Using `cover?` allows the user to switch out the range of numerics for a range of custom objects in the future.

Comment: Isn't your point the opposite of what you argue in your answer? By using `include?` with a numeric range now it will invoke `cover?` on the numeric range but if the receiver is changed in future to a non-numeric range (or possibly to an array) you *may* not have to change the code here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland that depends how you look at it. Since we're looking at a time I assume the range will not be exchanged for an array. Say we passed some `ActiveSupport::RimeWithZone` as range objects. `cover?` requires an object to implement `<=>` and `include?` requires an object to implement `succ`. Using `(2.years.ago..0.days.ago).cover?(2.weeks.ago)` would only compare to the begin and end of the range out of the box. (1/2)

Comment: Using `include?` would generate a huge list, since `succ` only adds a single second. Where it not for the fact that [Rails prepends to Range](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/601006c56d08f8ce168faf7b5875a9a19a026001/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/range/include_time_with_zone.rb) to handle their own case. (2/2)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html) mapping the previous matches to the timestamp that it started at.

Then for each current_match, do a `fetch` to get the timestamp if present, and then test whether the timestamp meets the condition.

If `previous_matches_collection` had `1000` things and `current_matches` has `300` then this is `1300` hash operations, each of which is `O(1)`.  This should scale better than your current solution.

Comment: I think you've assumed that item_id is unique in the previous and/or current matches, which isn't the case. I've just added some sample data to the question

Comment: @TomDunning I did.  But no big deal, if it is not unique, then simply narrowing it down to a list of timestamps is still a big win.  (If there were a lot a lot of records, then you could do a binary search.)

Answer (score 1):

```
h = previous_matches_collection.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  id = g[:item_id]
  h[id] = (h[id] || []) << g[:start_time_range]
end
  #=> {1=>[1597094393.6195982..1597094396.6195982,
  #        1597095081.616646..1597095084.616646,
  #        1597095401.528223..1597095404.528223],
  #    2=>[1597098033.556944..1597098036.556944],
  #    3=>[1597096071.9109557..1597096074.9109557],
  #    4=>[1597094784.1987526..1597094787.1987526,
  #        1597098075.91271..1597098078.91271]}
```

```
current_matches.select do |g|
  id = g[:item_id]
  h.key?(id) && h[id].any? { |a| a.cover?(g[:start_time]) }
end
  #=> [{:item_id=>1, :start_time=>1597094395.919598},
  #    {:item_id=>1, :start_time=>1597095404.228223}]
```

See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) and [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

If the first expression if `h` does not have a key `id = g[:item_id]`, `h[id] = (h[id] || [])` sets `h[id] #=> []` (because `(h[id] || []) => (nil || []) => []`) after which `h[id] << g[:start_time_range]` is executed. One could alternatively write

```
h = previous_matches_collection.
    each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |g,h|
  h[g[:item_id]] << g[:start_time_range]
end
```

This makes the object `h` an initially-empty hash with a default proc that executes `h[k] = []` if `h[k]` is executed when `h` has no key `k`. See the third form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new).

Comment: I think cover? and include? have similar performance when the begin and end of the range are numeric. I just ran a quick test and confirmed it. Do you disagree @Cary Swoveland?

Comment: @Les, see my comment on 3limin4t0r's answer.